# failed to communicate with cluster: unauthorized Rancher 2.7 error while importing EKS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-eks, rancher

i am using 1.23 EKS & 2.7 Rancher, getting below error while importing existing EKS cluster into rancher.

> failed to communicate with cluster: unauthorized

The aws IAM user has administrative privileges  as well as all EKS privileges.

getting below error as well from

There are 0 nodes available to run the cluster agent. The cluster will not become active until at least one node is available

```
[ERROR] error syncing '_all_': handler user-controllers-controller: failed to start user controllers for cluster c-7mtgg: ClusterUnavailable 503: cluster not found, requeuing
```